# CruiseControl.net project that can skip completed tasks?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

A common problem I have with CruiseControl.net is when a project encounters an error (either related to the ccnet configuration or build errors) and once I fix the error I must start the project over from the start.  But in some cases this means hours of work that doesn't need to be redone.

Is there a method or design philosophy that will allow me to run sections of projects with more granularity?

I was considering passing in a number when force building and using that to determine which "stage" of the build to start at.

Comment: Clarify: you imply a build that takes *hours* to complete. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, some of our projects take hours to complete.  Compiling code, building assets, packaging, deploying, ect.  So perhaps I should just split all these steps into separate projects that force the next in the list?  But that feels less elegant and can cause other problems (like passing data to other projects and date changing overnight).

Comment: Absolutely, yes - break this monolithic and intractable behemoth up into a series of smaller, linked projects. Use the inbuilt trigger mechanisms and queue priority facilities to construct a build process which can be run from the beginning, or from a step where source changes, or from an ad-hoc manual forcebuild command. Take advantage of the functionality the CCNET environment provides to normalise, optimise and parallelise your build pipeline. This is the way it is *supposed* to work - it's not inelegant, it's absolutely the right way to do things.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your input!  I've started splitting up the project into smaller ones.  The parameter passing mechanism for triggered force builds is very important and I hadn't seen it before.